How to see Custom Events in GA4 User Activity
I have set up GA4 for my website and used Google Tag Manager to create events and triggers. The tags are all firing and I can see event counts for these custom events in the Google Analytics Dashboard in Home and Reports. However, these events are not showing up in any of the Explorations I'm trying to set up. Path Exploration shows up the default GA4 events like "session start" and "page view" but none of the specifics of what actual event was (I did set up events like page view for specific pages with their names, button clicks, etc). I'd like to dig deeper and see the specific user flows (i.e. know what button they clicked which led them to a particular page on the website). When I view User Activity, it also shows just the basic GA4 events. Is it possible to see these reports in more detail with the events I've set up in GTM? I've set up events for each page, including button clicks, etc.
tl;dr the events I set up in Google Tag Manager that do work are not showing up in any Exploration path or User Activity report.
Tried to verify tags were firing and they are. The rest of GA4 is logging events. It's just the Exploration path. Couldn't really find anything online about this issue specifically or how to troubleshoot.

Are you talking about the parameters you send along with the event in GTM?

@A_Patterson I suppose? As in, in GTM, I've set up many different tags to fire for different parameters. So tags for specific pages being viewed, specific buttons being clicked. I'd like to see what those are in the User Activity . i.e. I have a tag called industrial_services_button which fires when this specific button on a page is clicked. I'd like to see things like that in the User Activity rather than just "page_view"
